# NativeScript-Dev-Appium : UIElement.text() / UIElement.getAttribute("value") returns the automationText instead of the text displayed

Tags: appium, nativescript

I am using NativeScript-Dev-Appium@5.0.0 and wish to check for the text displayed on a label. I have automationText property assigned to the  and use Driver.findElementByAccessibilityId(automationTextValue) to get the element. The element is found, but when I try to use the UIElement.text() / UIElement.getAttribute("value") on it, it returns the value of the automationText attribute instead of the actual displayed text. Is there any other method to do it because I can't find any.

Comment: Would you mind giving the exact code you are using? I'm unsure whether you are using the wrapper library given by {N} or directly accessing the appium driver.

Comment: Can you post the html of the element from which you are fetching the text

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of NativeScript itself since when the automationText property is used, it will set all properties of the element like value, name, label etc. I would suggest you set the same text to automationText property and then you can access or test the element using something like this:

1. Using XPath:

```js
const el = await driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@name=\"My automation text\"]");
```

2. For Android only

```js
const el = await driver.findElementByText("My automation text");
const text =  await el.getAttribute("text");
```

3. Use imageVerification types like:

```js
await driver.compareRectangle
await driver.compareElement
await driver.compareScreen
```

Which is very convenient but the cons here is that this will require higher maintenance at some point.